# Overview control is shown nothing on collapsed is false

Tags: openlayers-3

```
let map = new ol.Map({
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [16110, 16262],
    zoom: 12,
    minZoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 20
  }),
  controls: [
    new ol.control.Zoom({
      className: "ol-zoom-plugin"
    }),
    new ol.control.Attribution({
      className: "ol-attribution ol-attribution-plugin",
      collapsible: false
    }),
    new ol.control.OverviewMap({
      collapsible: false
    })
  ],
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([dragZoom])
});
```

By this code ol.control.OverviewMap (collpasible false) is div with overview empty without box etc. Main ol.Map is showing right. I think, this is bug. Or my mistake?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: This problem is solved by adding map.addControl after ol.Map constructor.